# Pixel Game in Android

Tags: android, 2d-games

I am making a Game in Android using Android Studio. My Game is beign designed in Pixel Art.

The images that I put on the Game, in the app, are shown with Smooth, they are not pixelated as I have designed.

Is there a way to put the images and show them correctly? Here is an example of what happens. At left, how my App shows the images. At right, how do I need to be shown thw images.

https://stuartspixelgames.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/comparison.png?w=700

Answer (score 0):

What is the supposed size of this image on screen? Perhaps your image file's dimensions are too big sometimes it becomes blur depending also on how you display it.

Comment: Hello. I'm making the Game with tiles, each tile is 30x30 I dont want the user views the 30x30 but is there a way to do a zoom, for example of 200? Or something like this?